# Retina display in android simulator

Tags: android, css, cordova, retina-display

Is it possible to have an equivalent to retina display (device-pixel-ratio: 2) in Android `Emulator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have retina display in default emualators provided by Android-sdk so far, But don't know if that being provided by Third party skin/emulator for device.